# Different output with brackets for if statement in TWO SUM proble

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, syntax, brackets

I am attaching here the link to the TWO SUM problem in leet code: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    *returnSize=2;
    int *arr=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<numsSize-1;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<numsSize;j++){
            printf("i= %d j=%d,ans=%d\n",nums[i],nums[j],nums[i]+nums[j]);
            if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target){
               arr[0]=i; arr[1]=j;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

In the `if statement` of the above code upon adding the curly braces produces the following output[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX0kt.png)

but if i removed the curly braces of `if statement` then i get a different output as shown [bracket of if statement removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sOC3.png)

Comment: You should always use curly braces to prevent from this type of errors. Not only "even for one line blocks" (this is a good example), but "even for one sentence blocks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without curly braces, only the first statement after the `if` (`arr[0]=i`) gets executed. While if the curly braces of the `if` are present, all the statements within the curly braces are executed.

Comment: And that's why you don't cram two statements into one line.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I didnt see that properly.

Answer (score 3):

Without using braces in this if statement

```
if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target){
   arr[0]=i; arr[1]=j;
}
```

you actually have

```
if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target) arr[0]=i; 
arr[1]=j;
```

So this statement

```
arr[1]=j;
```

executes unconditionally.

You could use for example one statement with a comma operator expression like

```
if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target)
   arr[0]=i, arr[1]=j;
```

to get the expected result.

Pay attention to that your approach is inefficient. The nested loops should stop their iterations as soon as the required pair of elements of the array is found.

This parameter

```
int* returnSize
```

does not make a sense because the object pointed to by this pointer is always set to 2.

The dynamically allocating memory is not a good idea.

Also you did not initialize the allocated memory. So if the required pair of elements of the array is not found you are returning an array with indeterminate values.

I would declare and define the function the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Pair 
{ 
    size_t first;
    size_t second;
};


struct Pair twoSum( const int *nums, size_t numsSize, int target )
{
    struct Pair pair = { .first = numsSize, .second = numsSize };
    
    int found = 0;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; !found && i < numsSize; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; !found && j < numsSize; j++ )
        {
            if ( nums[i] + nums[j] == target )
            {
                found = 1;
                pair.first = i;
                pair.second = j;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return pair;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int a1[] = { 2, 7, 11,15 };
    size_t n = sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( *a1 );
    
    int target = 9;
    
    struct Pair pair = twoSum( a1, n, target );
    
    if ( pair.first != n )
    {
        printf( "[%zu,%zu]\n", pair.first, pair.second );
    }
    
    int a2[] = { 3, 2, 4 };
    n = sizeof( a2 ) / sizeof( *a2 );
    
    target = 6;
    
    pair = twoSum( a2, n, target );
    
    if ( pair.first != n )
    {
        printf( "[%zu,%zu]\n", pair.first, pair.second );
    }
    
    int a3[] = { 3, 3 };
    n = sizeof( a3 ) / sizeof( *a3 );
    
    target = 6;
    
    pair = twoSum( a3, n, target );
    
    if ( pair.first != n )
    {
        printf( "[%zu,%zu]\n", pair.first, pair.second );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
[0,1]
[1,2]
[0,1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation !
But that `*returnsize = 2` still confuses me in leetcode. I thought it is the size of the array that we are going to return, so we need to fix the size for it

Comment: @ABINESH You could wrap an array for example in a structure like struct Pair { size_t arr[2]; }; and return an object of the structure.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't work like Python (and maybe some other languages), in terms of indentation, and the compiler doesn't interpret your two *separate* statements after the `if (...)` as being the body of the conditional block. So, without the curly braces, only the *first* statement (`arr[0]=i;`) forms the conditional block, and the second statement (`arr[1]=j;`) is executed regardless of the result of the test.

The body of an `if` block is either a *single* statement or a 'scope block' (sometimes known as a *compound* statement), delimited by the `{ ... }` braces.